# Are there non-brute-force algorithms for longest or shortest beta reduction path?

Tags: complexity-theory, lambda-calculus

Consider the related problems of, given a strongly normalizing lambda term, computing the longest and shortest paths ending in a normal form.

In terms of bits of input the optimal complexity is some uncomputable function (since the input can be a Busy Beaver etc.). But the complexity of brute force is still quite large even in terms of the result, is there a faster algorithm than bfs/computing the whole graph?